# Loop through and copy paste values without repetition if conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

Im trying to create a table that pulls data from my raw data if certain conditions are met. The code I currently have does not seem to be working.

```
Public Sub insert_rows()
    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim datasheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    
    Dim tableA As ListObject
    
    
    Set tableA = Worksheets(Sheet7).ListObject(Preventable)
    Set datasheet = Worksheets(Sheet7)
    Set datasheet2 = Worksheets("Data")
    
    With datasheet2
        nr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1up).Row
        For r = 1 To nr
            If Cells(r, 17) = "Y" Then
                Cells(r, 16).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet7").Range("B4")
            End If
        Next
    End With   
End Sub
```

Basically I have several worksheets and need to pull data from one of them to add to this table in another worksheet. My condition is if the Column in the raw data worksheet contains "Y", then pull cell values into the table of the other worksheet. An image below is an example of the data I want to copy and paste over:

[image: Screenshot of Raw Data]

As you can see, they are string values separated by "," and can contain duplicates.

I only want to add just the unique entries into the new table; with no repetition of cells. Anyway I could modify this code to suit those conditions?

Comment: Notice your code is not using `With` properly. Inside your `With` block, if you type `Cells` you are calling the **ACtiveSheet** (that maybe is not `datasheet2`. Add a dot before each object. Change it to `.Cells` or `.Rows.Count`

Comment: Do you want to create two rows from "HE (Technical), HE (Process)" - if not yet in target list?

Comment: Within your loop you use `Cells(r, 16).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet7").Range("B4")`, which pastes from each loop into the same cell.  Is that supposed to be appended to the last row in column B on sheet7, or what's the intent?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Public Sub insert_rows()
    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim datasheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, nr As Long
    Dim tableStartingRow As Long, currenttableitem As Long
    Dim stringvalues As Variant
    Dim stringseparator As String
    Dim valueexists As Boolean
    
    tableStartingRow = 4
    stringseparator = ","
    Set datasheet = Worksheets("Sheet7")
    Set datasheet2 = Worksheets("Data")
    
    With datasheet
        currenttableitem = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    With datasheet2
        nr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 1 To nr
            If .Cells(r, 17) = "Y" Then
                If InStr(.Cells(r, 16), stringseparator) > 0 Then 'If value contains comma
                    stringvalues = Split(.Cells(r, 16), stringseparator)
                    For i = LBound(stringvalues) To UBound(stringvalues)
                        valueexists = False 'Reset boolean
                        For x = tableStartingRow To currenttableitem
                            If datasheet.Range("B" & x).Value = Trim(stringvalues(i)) Then
                                valueexists = True
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next x
                        
                        If Not valueexists Then
                            currenttableitem = currenttableitem + 1
                            datasheet.Range("B" & currenttableitem).Value = Trim(stringvalues(i))
                        End If
                        
                    Next i
                Else
                    valueexists = False 'Reset boolean
                    For x = tableStartingRow To currenttableitem
                        If datasheet.Range("B" & x).Value = .Cells(r, 16).Value Then
                            valueexists = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next x
                    
                    If Not valueexists Then
                        currenttableitem = currenttableitem + 1
                        datasheet.Range("B" & currenttableitem).Value = .Cells(r, 16).Value
                    End If

                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
End Sub
```

This code will check each value of the cells and will split the contents by `","`. Then compare with the content of the table to see if this value is already in there. In case it is not, it will be added, otherwise omitted.

Also, I notice the use of the `Cells` inside of a `With` statement. That was making a reference to the active worksheet. To make reference to the item in the With statement, you need to use `.Cells`

I hope this will help.

Comment: I'm fairly new to VBA coding so I really appreciate the explanations for the lines of code. Do I need to have a subroutine code to run this? Like a command button to execute the code? Currently I'm getting a subscript out of range error I'm trying to figure out the cause.

Comment: Well you can add one if you want but this should be able to run also directly from the VBA Editor. Could you Debug the code (with Step Into - F8 button) to see exactly which line is generating the error?

Comment: I get the Error 9 (subscript out of range) on the ` Set datasheet2 = Worksheets("Data")` section when I use the F8 button. When I run the code, it does not highlight the line nor does it give me the option to debug.

Comment: Is the raw data worksheet named Data and the other one Sheet7? That error usually appears when the sheet name does not exists in the workbook.